# How to move track scene from one .file to another

Tags: node-editor, camera, scene

How do i transfer a movie/pic sequence with its camera tracking, from one blend file to another?

I'm new to render and for each file I make, I have an awful time ruining my blend file, without being able to fix them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. I don't understand, are you willing to make a safe copy of your tracking work, just in case it gets ruined because of some error? In this case simply saving the file and making a copy of it would be much easier, imho.

Comment: The easiest way would be to save the file with a different name

Comment: Jeah sounds good. Just trying to learn the easiest way around in blender. I have ruined at least 10 files because ive been messing around with all my different settings